# highlight an imagebutton without another image

Tags: android, imagebutton

I was just wondering if there is a way to highlight an imagebutton when pressed without using another image as the highlighted one. thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the selected background. Set the backgorund of the view to @selected_background